# Finds any values that start with 2 and are at least 3 characters in length

Tags: sql, database

I am learning SQL and came around this

> Q: Finds any values that start with 2 and are at least 3 characters in length.
>
> A: **WHERE SALARY LIKE '2_%_%**'
>
> [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm) - under the EXAMPLES

**My Question**

Would **WHERE SALARY LIKE '2_ _%'** also solve the question?

Comment: why is salary a string?

Comment: @Greg Well in real world maybe not, but for the sake of an example salary is a string here.

Answer (score 5):

All of the three are correct,
i.e.
`WHERE SALARY LIKE '2_%_%'`

`WHERE SALARY LIKE '2__%'`

`WHERE salary LIKE '2%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(salary) >= 3`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, it wouldn't work. You should use two verifications, something like:

```
WHERE `salary` LIKE '2%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(`salary`) >= 3
```

**EDIT:** Would work though. See the official docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html (see second paragraph and fourth example)

Comment: You mean to say even WHERE SALARY LIKE '2_%_%' wouldn't work?

Comment: It must be,`WHERE salary LIKE '2%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(salary) >= 3`  as it says atleast three characters.

Comment: @AnupamMajhi No sorry, your example is good, the underscore symbol can be used to match any single character. With this in mind, your answer would also be valid. I misread the original post, my bad :)

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent But more than 2 sources only show the first way to be correct. That's why I wanted to know if there is any advantage in using the first solution if my solution is also correct. Will wait for few more replies :)

Comment: @AnupamMajhi Good for me! :) But as far as I'm concerned, the official docs goes the same way: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html (see second paragraph and fourth example).